# Getting a series of errors when trying to update Conda and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I neglected to update my conda installation for a long time.  It was version 4.1-ish, running Python 3.5.2.  I finally decided to make the switch to Python 3.9, but I have been having some trouble getting everything to update.  I started by running commands like

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda update python
conda update -all
```

repeatedly and made a fair amount of progress, but eventually conda reached a steady state and won't go any further.

Now I have conda version 4.5.11 and python 3.5.6.  When I run `conda update conda` or `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`, it returns

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.13.0
```

but then doesn't install it.

When I try `conda install conda=4.13.0`, I get

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - conda=4.13.0
  - pymc
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Similarly, when I try `conda install python=3.9` or `conda install python=3.7`, it gives me

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - healpy -> python=3.5 -> libffi=3.2
  - healpy -> python=3.5 -> openssl=1.0
  - healpy -> python=3.5 -> readline=7
  - python=3.9

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - _nb_ext_conf -> python=3.5
  - python=3.7
```

Could I get 3.9 to work by doing `conda remove pymc` and `conda remove healpy`?  Will that break anything?  Is there a better way to upgrade conda/anaconda/python?

Update: I executed `conda remove pymc` and then tried `conda install conda=4.13.0` again.  Now I get

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - conda=4.13.0 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a']
  - python=3.5
```

Comment: Does creating a new environment with `conda create -n py39 python==3.9` work? A little confused as to what `conda install python=3.9` will achieve.

Comment: Creating the new environment seems to have gotten python 3.9 to download.  However, now my jupyter notebooks aren't working in either environment.  I click run on the cells and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem.
Although it is not exactly a solution, installing a fresh new Anaconda distribution has worked for me:

1. Access the [Anaconda's oficial website](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) and download the Python 3.9 64-Bit installer for Linux.
2. Before starting the new installation, you may back up your previous environments ([see this reference](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/how-to-clone-python-working-environment-on-another-machine)) and restore it later.
3. If you are not confident in losing your previous envs, you can make a copy of your *.bashrc* and *.bash_profile* files and choose a different installation path for the new distribution.